# Reloading multiple application servers on deploy

Tags: php, web-applications, deployment, cron, reload

I have a setup where there are several application servers running `php-fpm` service and they all share a `GlusterFS` mount for the application code and other assets. In the current deploy process, the files get updated directly on the file server and many times to reflect changes the application service must be reloaded. To achieve that, the deployment script needs to get into every server and issue a reload command but with autoscaling, the number of servers is not the same at every moment.

Overall, I am working on sketching a couple of alternatives to solution this problem:

- First one, more artesanal and not perfect, as a proof of concept, would be a cron job that will run every X minutes on the application machines and look for a file that should contain a unique info like it's hostname or IP address. If it matches, it will not take action but if not, it will reload and write itself within the file. On the deployment procedure, the script would clear the file and all servers should get reloaded in the next cron run.
- Second, using a more sophisticated approach like a message queue or notification service where the running applications machine would subscribe to at boot time and wait for an order to reload. Deploy script would then publish a notification to get all servers aware it is time. A similar cron job from the previous method would then notice that and reload the app server.

Would any of that make sense? Is there any simpler or more standard way to trigger a broadcast for the applications servers running at a given moment in the deploy procedure without having to ssh to each and issuing the reload command? Any other advice you can provide or other suggestions?

Thanks!